# What could be the potential reasons for difference in the outputs of a DL model on GPU and CPU?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, cpu, huggingface-transformers

Here is the code that I ran on two devices :

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/roberta2roberta_L-24_wikisplit")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("google/roberta2roberta_L-24_wikisplit")

long_sentence = """Due to the hurricane, Lobsterfest has been canceled, making Bob very happy about it and he decides to open Bob 's Burgers for customers who were planning on going to Lobsterfest."""

input_ids = tokenizer(tokenizer.bos_token + long_sentence + tokenizer.eos_token, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
output_ids = model.generate(input_ids)[0]
print(tokenizer.decode(output_ids, skip_special_tokens=True))
```

I am getting two completely different outputs. The model performs perfectly on my local machine but outputs random gibberish on GPU. What could be the reasons for such a behaviour?

I compared the weights after loading them on the respective devices and they match perfectly. The output of the encoder block is also same for the two devices. That means, something is wrong with the Decoder part but I am not sure what. What am I missing here?

Here is the input that I gave : 'She tries to find the appropriate wording and context in English that would correspond to the work in Spanish.'

Output on GPU : 'She to to find the appropriate wording and context.'

Output on CPU : 'She tries to find the appropriate wording and context in English. That would correspond to the work in Spanish.'

For this sentence, the model performs poorly on GPU and doesn't segment the sentence. And sometimes, there is also some noise added by the model. In the above sentence for example, 'tries' changes to 'to'. So not only it is unable to segment the input sentence, it is also adding noise to the final output.

Comment: Could you please add the outputs from both the devices?

Comment: I have edited the question and added outputs of both the devices. Thanks.